# How to avoid iframe from reloading parent page and messing the history?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, sandbox

I have a chrome extension with two nested iframes (to avoid CORS issues). The outer iframe is simply a wrapper pointing to an HTML page that loads the inner iframe. The inner iframe loads my website that makes API requests.

After the inner iframe fetches a request, it causes the parent website to reload - when I click the browser back button, the API calls are re-triggered without any navigation. I believe the parent website adds itself to the history stack when the API call is made.

Interestingly, I experience this issue only when I point my inner iframe to my deployed website. When I point it to `localhost`, there is no muddying of history.

How do I prevent the main website from reloading when the back button is pressed? I have already sandboxed both my iframes without the top-navigation permission.

**inner.js**

```js
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.width = "100%";
iframe.height = "100%";
iframe.src = "website URL" // this makes GQL requests
(<any>iframe).sandbox = "allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-forms allow-modals";
document.body.appendChild(iframe)
```

**inner.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Website</title>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="width: 100%; height: 100vh" id="iframeWrapperBody">
    <script src="inner.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**outer.js (content script)**

```js
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
(<any>iframe).sandbox = "allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups";
document.body.appendChild(iframe); 
iframe.contentWindow?.location.replace(chrome.runtime.getURL("inner.html"));
```

Comment: The exact sequence of events sounds vague. Try investigating what happens by setting a breakpoint on navigation-related events: https://i.imgur.com/ynVeYE5.png